# How to put OR on pdo select query where condition?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

```
$sql = "SELECT message FROM sale WHERE seller_id=? && payment_date=? && bank=?";

$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result = $q->execute(array($user_id, $paydate, bank1|| bank2|| bank3));
```

how to correct the mistake of "bank1 || bank2 || bank3" ?

Comment: shouldn't you add `php` tag to this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT message FROM sale WHERE seller_id=? AND payment_date=? 
    AND bank IN (?, ?, ?)";

$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result = $q->execute(array($user_id, $paydate, $bank1, $bank2  $bank3));
```

If you have a dynamic number of banks (e.g. in an array $banks):

```
$sql = "SELECT message FROM sale WHERE seller_id=? AND payment_date=? ";

$values = array($user_id, $paydate);

if ($banks) {
  $sql .= " AND bank IN (" . implode(",",array_fill(0,count($banks),"?")) . ")";
  $values = array_merge($values, array_values($banks));
}

$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result = $q->execute($values);
```

PS: I recommend using `AND` and `OR` in SQL instead of `&&` and `||`.  In standard SQL, `||` is the string concatenation operator. You'd be wise to develop the habit of writing standard SQL when  you can.

Answer (score 0):

Hold the banks inside an array and then place the array inside the execution statement.  But also you must change `&& bank=` to `&& bank in ()`,  due to the dynamic amount of banks you'll query.